# Improving performance of native sql query in spring/hibernate applicaiton?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring, hibernate

I have below the `native sql query`. i am using `Oracle` database.

```
select
         * 
     from
         (select
             row_.*,
             rownum rownumber 
         from
             (select
                 colmn1,
                 colmn2,
                 colmn3,
                 colmn4,
                 colmn5,
                 colmn6,
                 from
                 Table5
             where
                 colmn5 In (
                    '19901','10001'
                 ) 
             order by
                colmn1 ) row_ ) 
         Where
             Rownumber <= 50000
             and rownumber > 0
```

Above query returns `50000` records. if i execute above query in `sqldeveloper`, it takes only `30 seconds` but in the spring and hibernate integrated application it takes `15 minutes`. How can i improve the performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two inner selects. An inner select always is a possible source of bad performance, because it might hinder the database from finding the optimal search strategy.

As far ar I can see you use the inner selects only for handling the row number. If you use only the most inner select and handle the row number on java/hibernate level, then you'll get a much better performance.

You only use this select

```
select colmn1, colmn2, colmn3, colmn4, colmn5, colmn6,
   from Table5
   where colmn5 In ('19901','10001') 
   order by colmn1
```

which, as it does not have any database specialities any more easily can be replaced by an HQL statement and so making your program independent of the used database (Java class and property names should be replaced by the real ones):

```
from Table5_Class
   where colmn5_Prop in ('19901','10001') 
   order by colmn1_prop
```

Then you replace your where condition `Where Rownumber <= 50000 and rownumber > 0` by the hibernate methods `Query.setMaxResults(50000)` and `Query.setFirstResult(0)` (remark: setFirstResult(0) is superfluous as row 0 always is the first one, but I guess you also want to get the next 50000 rows, and then you can use setFirstResult(n)).

If you need the rownumber as a parameter then you can use the index of the resulting List for this.

P. S: I can't tell you why your select is so much faster in the SQL developer than in Hibernate.